# Изменение значения в массиве

Tags: массивы, excel, vb.net, interop

Во-первых Interop.Excel благополучно превращает "." в "," при заполнении Range данными из массива Object(,).

Во-вторых (что стало вообще огромной неожиданностью для меня), значения не изменяются при вызове `Replace` для элементов массива:

```
Dim tempArr As Object(,) = wb2.ActiveSheet.usedrange.value2
For Each myVal In tempArr
    If myVal IsNot Nothing Then myVal = Replace(myVal.ToString, ".", "")
Next
```

После выполнения кода значения в tempArr все еще содержат точки. При чем, в myVal все отлично, данные меняются! Но вот массив остается нетронутым.

Подскажите неразумному, а что массив объектов - это не ссылочный тип?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для первой проблемы недостаточно данных для воспроизведения. Попробуйте расписать ее поподробнее, привести примеры и оформить отдельным вопросом.

Для второй, поясню: `myVal` это переменная, которая ссылается на объект (элемент массива). После того как Вы присваиваете ей значение:

```
myVal = Replace(myVal.ToString, ".", "")
```

переменная ссылается на новый объект (строка с заменами), оригинальный же объект в массиве не изменился.

В общем и целом, `For Each` не подходит для замены содержимого массива, о чем написано [в официальном руководстве](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/):

> **Traversing Arrays.** Because the Array class implements the IEnumerable interface, all arrays expose the GetEnumerator method. This means that you can iterate through an array with a For Each...Next loop. However, you can only read the array elements. **You cannot change them.**

Можно попробовать создать новый массив и переприсвоить, но в данном случае проще использовать двойной `For`:

```
For i As Integer = tempArr.GetLowerBound(0) To tempArr.GetUpperBound(0)
    For j As Integer = tempArr.GetLowerBound(1) To tempArr.GetUpperBound(1)
        If tempArr(i,j) IsNot Nothing Then 
             tempArr(i,j) = Replace(tempArr(i,j).ToString, ".", "")
        End If
    Next 
Next
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я так и сделал уже. Просто не ожидал что "...However, you can only read the array elements. You cannot change them."